# NgModule provider isn't providing service in Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, provider

So I am starting to learn angular and have just started looking into services and dependency injection. I created a very basic service and was attempting to use providers to be able to use the service in the component. However, in the component it gives me the error

> Cannot find name 'CourseService'

The quick fix is to directly import the service into the component, however I know that is bad practice and goes against the point of services and providers.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CourseService } from './courses.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [CourseService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
//import { CourseService } from './courses.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  CList:string[];

  constructor(service: CourseService){
    this.CList=service.getCourses();
  }
}
```

**courses.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CourseService {
  getCourses(){
    return ["course1", "course2", "course3"];
  }
  constructor() {   
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I was under the impression that a direct import would not make it a singleton and therefore break it. Apparently providedIn root handles that.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this line in app.component.ts:

```
//import { CourseService } from './courses.service';
```

By the way, if you use the *providedIn* property with 'root' within an injectable decorator, you can just delete the service from the app.module providers array, because CoursesService will be injected as a singleton service already.

https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#providedIn

Comment: Thank you. I assumed that importing directly to a component was bad, and didn't realize making it injectable fixed it. In that case what is the point of providers in a Module, I assumed they would be used for injecting services but according to this that isn't necessary.

Comment: Importing directly to a component assumes a special use case, where you pretty much in need of individual services per component. If that's not the case, you might end up with multiple services, since you may have a dozen of the same component at any time.

Injecting the service as a module's provider is a higher level though. If you really want to make sure you don't end up with multiple services of the same type, then just use the `providedIn` property on the service and delete it from everywhere else.